# how to design a class that where I can store and retrieve data using class properties/method

Tags: c#

I would like to do something like below where I should be able to store and retrieve data though class properties or method,

```
 //set the value
        var someObject = {... };

        var newMessage = new Message(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(someObject))
        {
            ContentType = "application/json"
        };

        //get the value
        Message message;
        var x = message.GetBody<string>()
```

I tried creating class like below, but have to supply body for method. How to design this class?

```
public class Message
{
    public Message(object serializableObject);
    public string SessionId { get; set; }
    public string ContentType { get; set; }

    public T GetBody<T>();
}
```

Comment: I have **no** idea what you expect e.g. `x` to be equal to at the end of the first snippet. Maybe it's clear *to you* but bear in mind we have *no context* here to work out what you're doing.

Comment: Ok, ignore the `get` part. Can we design a class where I'm setting the value

Comment: It should be noted that `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(someObject)` returns a **`string`**, so why does your constructor `public Message(object serializableObject)` use `object` instead of `string`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand your question, but you've missed out on the constructor

```
new Message(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(someObject)) //<-- string is passed
```

I think you have misinterpreted the `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(someObject)` statement, it will return a string not an object. Whereas you have used the incorrect type as an argument for your constructor.

```
public Message(object serializableObject); // should be a string
```

To correct your class, you need to design it the following way...

```
public class Message
{
    private readonly string _json;

    public Message(string json)
    {
        _json = json;            
    }

    public string GetBody() // not generic, but you get the idea now.
    {
        return json;
    }
}
```